# A Cauchy Sequence is a Cauchy Sequence in a space iff is a Cauchy sequence in another space.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

So again I was studying topology and came across this problem:

Show that given two metric spaces $(X, d_1), (X, d_2)$ such that $d_2(x,y)=\frac{d_1(x,y)}{1+d_1(x,y)}$. A sequence will be a Cauchy sequence in the first space iff is a Cauchy sequence in the second.

So here's my attempt:

$\Rightarrow x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X, d_1)$ we want to prove that $x_n$ is also Cauchy in $(X, d_2)$

Since $x_n$ is Cauchy in $(X, d_1) \rightarrow d_1(x_n, x_m)<\epsilon$ for all $n,m \geq 0$ and $n, m \in Z_+$ and $\epsilon >0$.

$d_1(x_n, x_m)< \epsilon$

$\implies d_1(x_n, x_m) < \epsilon + \epsilon d_1(x_n, x_m)$

$\implies d_1(x_n, x_m)< \epsilon (1+ d_1(x_n,x_m))$

$\implies \frac{d_1(x_n,x_m)}{1+d_1(x_n,x_m)}<\epsilon$

And the inequalities don't change because everything added, multiplied or divided is positive.

$\Leftarrow x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X, d_2)$ we want to prove that $x_n$ is also Cauchy in $(X, d_1)$

Since $x_n$ is Cauchy in $(X, d_2) \rightarrow d_1(x_n, x_m)<\epsilon$ for all $n,m \geq 0$ and $n, m \in Z_+$ and $\epsilon >0$.

$\implies \frac{d_1(x_n, x_m)}{1+d_1(x_n,x_m)}<\epsilon$

$\implies d_1(x_n, x_m)< \epsilon + \epsilon d_1(x_m,x_m)$

$\implies d_1(x_n, x_m) -\epsilon d_1(x_nm x_m) < \epsilon$

$\implies d_1(x_n, x_m) (1-\epsilon) < \epsilon$

Since $\epsilon$ here cannot be greater than 1, we take $\epsilon \in (0,1)$

$\implies d_1(x_n,x_m) < \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$

$\implies d_1(x_n, x_m) < \delta$
And $\delta >0$

That's my work, is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is fine. The second part has two errors. You cannot say $\epsilon$ cannot be greater than $1$. Also you did not complete the proof.

Let $\epsilon' >0$ be arbitrary.  Choose $\epsilon >0$ such that $\frac {\epsilon} {1-\epsilon} =\epsilon'$ which means $\epsilon= \frac {\epsilon'} {1+\epsilon'} $. Then we get  $d_1(x_n,x_m) <\epsilon'$ finishing the proof. For the case $\epsilon \geq 1  $ find $n_0$ such that $d_1(x_n,x_m) <\frac 1  2$ for $n,m \geq n_0$ and note that $d_1(x_n,x_m) <\epsilon$ for $n,m \geq n_0$.

Comment: Thank you @Kavi, isn't the second metric bounded by 1? since $\frac{x}{1+x}$ is bounded by 1 for positive real numbers?

Comment: Yes, but still it is wrong to say $\epsilon$ cannot be greater than $1$. In the definition of  Cauchy sequence $\epsilon$ can be any positive number.  @JocsanArielHernandezBarahon

Comment: Thank you @Kavi, you've been really helpful. I see your point.